# Drupal 7 find the path of a given file name

Tags: php

if this the folder path where I stored my file: file.tx

```
 $directory= variable_get('file_directory_path', 'sites/default/files');
```

how to get the path of a file: file.txt?

Comment: $filename = 'file.txt'; $path2file = $directory.'/'.$filename;

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. The below code with get the drupal file url.

```
$fileuri= variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files').'/file.tx';
$file_url = file_create_url(file_build_uri($fileuri));
```

For private folder use 'file_private_path'.

Mervyn